# How to make terminal in i3 transparent? (preferences tab not working)

Tags: command-line, configuration, i3-wm, terminator

I'm in i3 with terminator and I'm trying to make the terminal a little bit transparent to see my wallpaper 
but when i right click and go to preferences and i adjust the transparency nothing changes.

Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be called status by design, **transparency does not work in i3**.

[The compton FAQ](https://github.com/chjj/compton/wiki/faq#3-why-does-transparency-not-work-correctly-in-i3) explains why:

> Let’s face it: Using transparency (or ARGB background with transparent
> parts) on any window decorated by i3 is known to break.
>
> The problem is in how i3 adds title bars to windows. Unlike most
> window managers, i3 creates a completely separate window for the title
> bar (rather than wrapping it inside a frame window that contains both
> the application window and its title bar).

#### Further reading

- [i3wm’s reddit: Make terminals transparent?](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/2yytvs/make_terminals_transparent/)